# Find all elements sorted by best matches

Tags: go, mgo

I have some entities in my database called **"events"**. Each of these events contain an array of string, called **"tags"**.

I want to make a query to get all the events matching an array of tags that I will give in parameter.

BUT, I want these events to be sorted like:

- The first one is the one containing most of the tags I give in parameter.
- The second one is the second one containing most of the tags I give in parameter.
- And so on.

If there are more than one event containing the same amount of tags I want them to be sorted by their **"name"** property in **alphabetical order**.

**Example:**

- "name" = "event1", "tags" = ["food", "music", "gaming", "sport"]
- "name" = "event2", "tags" = ["gaming"]
- "name" = "event3", "tags" = ["music", "sport"]
- "name" = "event4", "tags" = ["food", "music", "gaming", "sport"]
- "name" = "event5", "tags" = ["music", "sport", "coding"]
- "name" = "event6", "tags" = ["coding"]
- "name" = "event7", "tags" = ["food", "gaming", "sport"]

The array of tags that I give in parameter for this example is: ["food", "music", "gaming", "sport"]

The result for this example will be an array of events, containing in that order:
**event1, event4, event7, event3, event5, event2**

To get all the events containing the tags I simply make a query with the **"$or"** operators. This allowed me to get all the events if they contained at least one of the tag given in parameter.

**Code:**

```golang
    var events []model.Event

    var MyQuery []map[string]interface{}
    for i := 0; i < len(tags); i++ {
        currentCondition := bson.M{"tags": tags[i]}
        MyQuery = append(MyQuery, currentCondition)
    }

    err := dbEvents.C(collectionEvents).Find(bson.M{"$or": OrQuery}).All(&events)
```

But i really don't know how to sort them like I showed you.

Comment: You can't do what you want using a query/sort. You can try using post-processing in your code, or aggregation pipeline coupled with some post-processing.

Comment: Ah.. Yes, that what I was thinking... Thanks for your answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"

    "github.com/ahmetb/go-linq"
)

type T struct {
    Name string
    Tags []string
}

func main() {
    params := []string{"food", "music", "gaming", "sport"}
    t := []T{
        T{Name: "event1", Tags: []string{"food", "music", "gaming", "sport"}},
        T{Name: "event2", Tags: []string{"gaming"}},
        T{Name: "event3", Tags: []string{"music", "sport"}},
        T{Name: "event4", Tags: []string{"food", "music", "gaming", "sport"}},
        T{Name: "event5", Tags: []string{"music", "coding", "sport"}},
        T{Name: "event6", Tags: []string{"coding"}},
        T{Name: "event7", Tags: []string{"food", "gaming", "sport"}},
    }
    var result []T
    linq.From(t).SortT(func(t1 T, t2 T) bool {
        var rs1 []string
        linq.From(t1.Tags).IntersectByT(linq.From(params), func(str string) string {
            return str
        }).ToSlice(&rs1)
        var rs2 []string
        linq.From(t2.Tags).IntersectByT(linq.From(params), func(str string) string {
            return str
        }).ToSlice(&rs2)
        return len(rs1) > len(rs2)
    }).ToSlice(&result)

    fmt.Printf("%+v", result)
}
```

> [{Name:event1 Tags:[food music gaming sport]} {Name:event4 Tags:[food music gaming sport]} {Name:event7 Tags:[food gaming sport]} {Name:event3 Tags:[music sport]} {Name:event5 Tags:[music coding sport]} {Name:event2 Tags:[gaming]} {Name:event6 Tags:[coding]}]

Above program sorts the array as per your requirements, Hope this will help you.

Comment: I will try, i'll let you know, thanks for the answer.
I assume with your response and the comment of Burak that I have to do it in a post process function because I can't do it directly with mongo.

Comment: Hello again,
It's working perfeclty, thank you very much.
I was thinking i could to it with Mongo direclty but apparently i was wrong.
Thanks so much.